# Video upload via FTP

Tags: 7, files

The [Video](http://drupal.org/project/video) module for Drupal 6 allows for video files uploaded via ftp to be played.  Does this module's Drupal 7 version have this feature?  If not what is the work around for large files?

Answer (score 5):

You can add this feature using the FileField Sources module. This module adds FTP (and more) upload to any FileField upload field, including the Video FileField upload field.

Comment: Can you give more specifics on how I can implement this? I have the modules uploaded, but I am having troubles figuring out how to pair them together.

Comment: On the field configuration page, you can configure which additional sources you want for the file or video field, besides the normal file upload source.